# understanding code pattern var factory = (0, _react.createFactory)(BaseComponent);

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was seeing the code of "withHandler.js" in npm module recompose and I came across the following code snippet
 `var factory = (0, _react.createFactory)(BaseComponent);`
 I am seeing this similar styled code snippet at many places in react libraries.
May please someone help understand, how to read this code snippet.
N.B. _react is react it was  defined as 
`_react= require('react')`

Comment: You are seeing the application of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: Thank you so much Jorj, I couldn't guess, it might be coming from babel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First learn how [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) works in JavaScript. It evaluates the operands from left to right and returns the last one. So, `(0, a.b)()` evaluates to `(a.b)()` and then `a.b()`.

Q: So, what's the point of `(0, a.b)()`? Why not `a.b()`?

A: When you write `a.b()`, `this` inside `b` refers to the `a` not to the global object. However in `(0, a.b)()` you're calling `b` while `this` refers to the global object.

So, calling `(0, _react.createFactory)(BaseComponent)` ensures that `this` inside `createFactory` function refers to the global object.